# 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'cell'

Tags: python, excel, colors, cell, openpyxl

I need to open an xlsx document and color it. But I don't understand why it shows cell error it. My algorithm works like this:

Open xlsx,  `writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='xlsxwriter')`

```
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

col_style = Font(name = "Reem Kufi", size = 12, color = "DB3B22", italic =True)

for i in range(2,40):
    worksheet.cell(row = i, column = 3).font = col_style
```

Error:- **'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'cell'**

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use the methods for one library on another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to use Openpyxl's `loadworkbook` instead of `ExcelWriter` to achieve what you are looking for. Updated code here. Note that I have only changed the initial open file and sheet using the new code and required libraries and not changed rest of your code.

```
from openpyxl.styles import Font
from openpyxl import load_workbook
writer = load_workbook(filename='YourFile.xlsx')

worksheet = writer['Sheet1']

col_style = Font(name = "Reem Kufi", size = 12, color = "DB3B22", italic =True)

for i in range(2,40):
    worksheet.cell(row = i, column = 3).font = col_style
    
writer.save('YourFile.xlsx')
```